# Routing works incorrectly with wireguard inside Docker network

Tags: linux, networking, dns, routing, wireguard

I'm not even sure that's the right wording, I'll try to explain.

I want to setup a small VPN are to host some private projects as well as access internet. I also want to have my own DNS server to have cool top level domain names.

## How does my setup look

I am using two Docker images:

- ubuntu/bind9 for DNS
- donaldzou/wgdashboard (https://github.com/donaldzou/WGDashboard) for Wireguard and GUI dashboard

My wireguard interface has name `main` and runs on port `20000`. Just a heads up because these aren't "default" settings.

Now, it almost works meaning I can connect several peers to this "server" peer. I can ping any peer from another peer. So the "wireguard" part of the setup works. I believe it is a routing issue that's outside wireguard scope.

Here's relevant parts of my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
services:
  dns:
    image: ubuntu/bind9
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      main:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.0.53 

  wgdashboard:
    image: donaldzou/wgdashboard
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_MODULE
    networks:
      main:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.0.2
    ports:
      - 10086:10086
      - 20000:20000/udp

networks:
  main:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.16.0.0/16
          ip_range: 172.16.0.0/24
          gateway: 172.16.0.1
```

Network is created and both containers have their correct IPs

So as my setup runs on UDP port 20000, and not on the `host` network, I have some rules in iptables. This part I'm super unsure about.

```
# iptables  -L | grep 20000
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             172.16.0.2           udp dpt:20000
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:20000
# iptables -t nat -L | grep 20000
MASQUERADE udp  --  172.16.0.2           172.16.0.2           udp dpt:20000
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:20000 to:172.16.0.2:20000
```

I've also seen some people requested this network info, so I'm posting it here:

```
$ ip -br link
lo               UNKNOWN        00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> 
ens3             UP             52:54:00:0c:f3:c5 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
docker0          DOWN           02:42:61:07:a5:d4 <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
br-e12a65bf943c  UP             02:42:5b:d4:1a:a6 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
$ ip -br address
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128 
ens3             UP             XX.YY.ZZ.24/24 
docker0          DOWN           172.17.0.1/16 
br-e12a65bf943c  UP             172.16.0.1/16 
$ ip route
default via XX.YY.ZZ.1 dev ens3 onlink 
XX.YY.ZZ.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src XX.YY.ZZ.24 
172.16.0.0/16 dev br-e12a65bf943c proto kernel scope link src 172.16.0.1 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
$ ip rule
0:  from all lookup local 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default 
$
```

## What's wrong

- I can ping and query `172.16.0.53` (the "dns" container) from server that runs docker
- I can ping and query `172.16.0.53` from "wgdashboard" container
- I can ping and query `1.1.1.1` from server and both containers
- I can ping and open `http://172.16.0.2:10086/` ("wgdashboard") container in browser from all connected peers
- I can NOT ping outside world from either peers
- I can NOT ping or issue a DNS query to `172.16.0.53` from either peers

---

## What I'm trying to do to troubleshoot this problem:

### port mapping

first, I added port mapping (`53:53/udp`) to `dns` service in docker-compose.yml:

```
$ docker-compose up
[+] Running 3/3
 ⠿ Network apps_main             Created                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.1s
 ⠿ Container apps-dns-1          Created                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.1s
 ⠿ Container apps-wgdashboard-1  Created                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.1s
Attaching to apps-dns-1, apps-wgdashboard-1
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint apps-dns-1 (4d28f6ed5232a08b266aed9fd232bc9894b7ae0990d25129b27d4f4112ef289f): Error starting userland proxy: listen udp4 0.0.0.0:53: bind: address already in use
```

uh what, does it try to bind to port 53 of host machine? Anyway I shouldn't need this anyway, because I only plan to query this server from inside of wireguard (and therefore, docker) network and don't need it from outside?

### tcpdump

I ran tcpdump from four locations:

- host machine, interface `br-e12a65bf943c` (docker-compose network), `tcpdump -i br-e12a65bf943c icmp`
- host machine, interface `ens3` (actual internet), `tcpdump -i ens3 icmp`
- wireguard container, interface `main` (like wg0 but i gave it the different name), `tcpdump -i main icmp`
- bind9 container, interface `eth0` (it's the only one there)

Pinging `dns` container from connected peer in chronological order (I don't know what's up with these timezones, ignore hours):

```
[wireguard,main]      16:18:22.021439 IP 10.0.0.2     > 172.16.0.53: ICMP echo request 
[host,br-e12a65bf943c]17:18:22.021500 IP 10.0.0.2     > 172.16.0.53: ICMP echo request 
[dns,eth0]            14:18:22.021508 IP 10.0.0.2     > 172.16.0.53: ICMP echo request 
[dns,eth0]            14:18:22.021567 IP 172.16.0.53  > 10.0.0.2:    ICMP echo reply   
[host,br-e12a65bf943c]17:18:22.021575 IP 172.16.0.53  > 10.0.0.2:    ICMP echo reply   
[host,ens3]           17:18:22.021584 IP 172.16.0.53  > 10.0.0.2:    ICMP echo reply
```

**takeaway: three requests,three replies, but one reply decided to go through `ens3` instead of returning to wireguard**

Pinging 1.1.1.1

```
[wireguard,main]      16:30:16.689460 IP 10.0.0.2 > 1.1.1.1: ICMP echo request
[host,br-e12a65bf943c]17:30:16.689570 IP 10.0.0.2 > 1.1.1.1: ICMP echo request
```

host machine, `ens3` has nothing (!!!)

**takeaway: I can't ping outside world from 10.0.0.0/16 network**

### So, I have three questions

- what happened with ICMP reply at `br-e12a65bf943c`? How to make it go back to wireguard interface?
- what happened with ICMP request on its way to 1.1.1.1?
- is it iptables

If you've read so far, thank you for your time

---

## Solution, I guess?

Thanks for answering! You're rignt, I forgot to mention the network mask, I selected /16 in this case.

Indeed, adding this route on `dns` container fixed pinging

```
ip route add 10.0.0.0/16 via 172.16.0.2
```

Now my task is to make it "permanent", I guess I need to add this to dockerfile or something.

Second issue is external traffic.

I added this rule to `wireguard` container:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/16 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

And yeah it looks like it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should have a route for `10.0.0.0/24` *(well, `/24` assumed since unprovided)* on the DNS container, with `172.16.0.2` as the nexthop (a.k.a. gateway). *Alternatively*, you'll need to (S)NAT (a.k.a. IP masquerade) ***inside*** the WG container (for at least traffics destined for `172.16.0.53:53`, UDP and maybe also TCP).

As for traffics to the Internet (e.g. `1.1.1.1`), it's probably because the firewall rules on the docker host added by the docker daemon do not allow traffics with source address other than `172.16.0.0/16` (`subnet:`) to be forwarded out from the `br-e12a65bf943c`. Again one of the options is to (S)NAT ***inside*** the WG container for traffics with source address in `10.0.0.0/24`.

The other option is to disable the corresponding filtering by some means, like preventing the docker daemon from touching the firewall at all (`--iptables=false`), or having something add the exception after the docker daemon is started.

I'm not entirely sure whether you'll need to add (S)NAT rule specifically for `10.0.0.0/24` on the docker host if you decide not to have the additional layer of NAT inside the WG container. You can check with `iptables-save` to see whether the current `SNAT`/`MASQUERADE` rule on the docker host is e.g. limited to source address within `172.16.0.0/16` for traffics from `br-e12a65bf943c`. Also with that decision you'll need to add route for `10.0.0.0/24` (with `172.16.0.2` as the nexthop) on the docker host as well.

Comment: I think I got this, I appended my post with what I've done. Does it look sensible? I now need to learn how to preserve these changes...

Comment: If you decide to NAT inside the WG container, then you don't even need to add the route in the DNS container.